# How to run this 'onchange' code onload?

Tags: javascript

I need to check onload if a list of checkboxes are checked. I know it needs a foreach loop because that's used in the onchange code too:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem){
    elem.onchange=function(){
        this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (this.checked) ? 'Not Visible' : "Visible";          
        var data = '#card-'+ this.id.split('-')[1];
        document.querySelector(data).classList.toggle('card-disabled');
        $.ajax({
            data: {data},
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backend/menu/disable-item.php',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log($("#visibilityList").serializeArray = data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How can I initialize this, so that it checks if a checkbox is already checked?

I tried using the 'window.onload' option but that isn't the way to go, obviously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that changes the view out of the event handler so that you can call it on page load as well as in the event handler. For example:

```js
var checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]'));

function update(checkbox) {
  checkbox.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = checkbox.checked ? 'Not Visible' : 'Visible';
  var cardId = 'card-' + checkbox.id.split('-')[1];
  document.getElementById(cardId).classList.toggle('card-disabled', checkbox.checked);
}

checkboxes.forEach(function(elem) {
  update(elem);
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    update(evt.target);
  });
});
```

```css
input{ float: left; }
[id^=card-] { display: inline-block; width: 2em; height: 2em; border: 1px solid green; }
.card-disabled { opacity: .2; }
```

```html
<div id="switch-wrapper-">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="x-1">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="x-2" checked>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="card-1">1</div>
<div id="card-2">2</div>
```

Note how in the `forEach` I'm calling `update` immediately as well as adding an event listener that calls it on change.

Comment: That's it.... almost! I would like to implement ajax in this, only if I change it. I do not get it to work tho, I've tried every possibility :(

Comment: @joostdelange That's very vague and well beyond the scope of your original question. If you're stuck on something else you should post a different question.

Comment: I changed my question with the ajax part in it, I just don't know where to put the ajax part in your example

Answer (score 0):

`Onchange` event fires when a value of checkbox changes 'checked' <=> 'not checked'. You can fire an event (and your listener as a result) using `dispatchEvent` but then state of your checkbox will change to the opposite.

Checkbox can be 'checked' on the page load if it has a property 'checked'. You can simply check if `checked` is true:

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (var box of boxes) {
  if (box.checked === true) { // checked?
    console.log(box)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="one">
<input type="checkbox" value="two" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="three">
```